# Why no apps really can get a correct UDID for my iphone?

Tags: iphone, testing, udid

I am going to make beta test for my new app and tried to find a simple way for my customers to get their UDIDs. Well, there are some apps on AppStore to get UDID. But none of them really work! They got completely different numbers than what I got from iTune! Can those UDIDs used to for beta test? I really doubt it.

Comment: You should read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"They got completely different numbers than what I got from iTunes! Can those UDIDs used to for beta test?" No they don't.
They use the `[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString` witch is different from the device's UDID. And change each time you reinstall the application.

You should use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) witch is fully automatic or [some simple page](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1536912) where the user can get it and send it to you, or make your own solution via PHP, read the official documentation about [OTA configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/iPhoneOTAConfiguration.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 7 app are no longer allowed to identify device. There for your apps can not retrieve the device `UDID` any more. You can't even readout the device mac address any more.

All `UDID` starting with `FFFFFF` can not be used and should not be enter in provisioning portal. Since it will not allow this device to access you Ad-Hoc builds.

Your beta test will have to retrieve there device `UDID` via iTunes or you can use a service like [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com/).

TestFlight will allow you user to register there device and you will be mailed there `UDID`, so there is no need for the user to connect there device to iTunes or Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

There **was** `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];` but this is deprecated since iOS5 (might be wrong) and finally removed in iOS7. This is why there are still apps that are capable to get it.

If you just want to identify the device, you can use this property of `UIDevice`.

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) NSUUID      *identifierForVendor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);      // a UUID that may be used to uniquely identify the device, same across apps from a single vendor.
```

Comment: @Itsraininggold wants to know how to get the `UDID` easily for registering his test user devices. Not how to identify device.

Comment: Yeah... I completely messed up the meaning of the OQ in my mind :P

Answer (score 1):

You can link your client to [whatsmyudid.com](http://whatsmyudid.com/). It would be much easier for them.

Answer (score 0):

There is two thing one is serial no and another is device id. Device id can be get easily by using the iTunes itself. There is no need to install any fancy app just for the sake getting the device id.PL see the attached images there to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question was about `UDID` apps that are no longer working, not on how to get the `UDID`.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for your comment. In his question he has mentioned ".... find a simple way for my customers to get their UDIDs..." so I thought this might be helpful.

Comment: True, I'm just finding iTunes is not an easy as user might not be behind a machine that has it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can send your clients links like http://get.udid.io/?mail=your@mail.com

Client will open this link on device, make 5 taps and you will receive letter to "your@mail.com" with UDID of device.